# Output regex in desired format

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

For the following code,

```
import re 
p = re.compile(r'\b(?:\w*[aeiou]){3}\w*',re.I)

print(p.findall('The group contains some of the most dangerous criminals in the country.'))
```

the regex is matching any word with at least 3 vowels in it.
the expected output format is

```
[('contains', 'ins'), ('dangerous', 'us'), ('criminals', 'als')]
```

(the second component will start with the last vowel to the last character of the word)

but I get

```
['contains', 'dangerous', 'criminals']
```

How to make it output on my expected format?

Comment: What are the rules of the expected output? How to decide if the second element in the tuple has 3 or 2 characters? Your regex is matching any word with at least 3 vowels in it. `findall` will not return tuples, unless you transform the result.

Comment: @knittl the second component will start with the last vowel to the last character of the word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options:

1. Match all the words, then transform the result with another regex (e.g. with a list comprehension):

   ```
   last_vowel = re.compile('\w*([aeiou]\w*)$', re.I);
   words = p.findall(…)
   print([(w, *last_vowel.findall(w)) for w in words])
   ```
2. Change your regex to capture the word and the last vowel in separate capturing groups:

   ```
   #                  vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv- first group
   p = re.compile(r'\b((?:\w*[aeiou]){2}\w*([aeiou]\w*))',re.I)
   #                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^-- second group
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single regex with 2 capture groups, where group 2 is inside group 1 starting with the last vowel to the last character of the word.

Then re.findall will return a list of  tuples of the 2 capture group values.

```
\b((?:\w*[aeiou]){2}\w*([aeiou]\w*))
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` A word boundary
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(?:\w*[aeiou]){2}` Repeat 2 times matching optional word chars and a vowel
  - `\w*` Match optional word chars
  - `([aeiou]\w*)` Capture **group 2**, match the 3rd vowel and optional word chars
- `)` Close group 1

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MZxVfu/1)

Example

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'\b((?:\w*[aeiou]){2}\w*([aeiou]\w*))', re.I)

print(p.findall('The group contains some of the most dangerous criminals in the country.'))
```

Output

```
[('contains', 'ins'), ('dangerous', 'us'), ('criminals', 'als')]
```